# Have issue with named queries not defined. I get java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No query defined for that name

Tags: spring

I have tried all possible fixes over the past few weeks. But this is very strange

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No query defined for that name [Organization.fetchAllOrganizations]
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.buildQueryFromName(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:908) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final] etc etc.

My DAO class

```
@Repository
public class OrgDao {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public List<OrganizationEntity> getAllOrgs() {
        return entityManager.createNamedQuery("Organization.fetchAllOrganizations", OrganizationEntity.class).getResultList();

    }

    public OrganizationEntity getOrgById(final Integer id) {
        return entityManager.createNamedQuery("Organization.fetchOrganizationById", OrganizationEntity.class).setParameter("id", id).getSingleResult();
    }
}
```

My Entity Class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "organization")
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Organization.fetchAllOrganizations", query = "SELECT O FROM OrganizationEntity O ORDER BY O.organizationName"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Organization.fetchOrganizationById", query = "SELECT Oi FROM OrganizationEntity Oi WHERE Oi.id=:id")
})

public class OrganizationEntity implements Identifier<Integer>, Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
-----
```

My Pom.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>BookingApp-Backend</artifactId>
        <groupId>BookingApp-Backend</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>BookingApp-Api</artifactId>

    <properties>
        <start.class>com.rudra.BookingApp.api.BookingAppApiApplication</start.class>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
             <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>BookingApp-Backend</groupId>
            <artifactId>BookingApp-Service</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
                    <artifactId>swagger-codegen-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.4.15</version>

                    <configuration>
                        <output>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources</output>
                        <language>spring</language>
                        <library>spring-boot</library>
                        <generateApis>false</generateApis>
                        <generateModels>true</generateModels>
                        <modelPackage>com.rudra.BookingApp.api.model</modelPackage>
                        <configOptions>
                            <java8>true</java8>
                            <sourceFolder>.</sourceFolder>
                            <dateLibrary>java8</dateLibrary>
                        </configOptions>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
                <artifactId>swagger-codegen-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
                        <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
                        <version>1.6.2</version>
                    </dependency>

                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
                        <artifactId>swagger-codegen-generators</artifactId>
                        <version>1.0.0-rc0</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>

                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>organization</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <inputSpec>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/endpoints/organization.json</inputSpec>
                            <language>spring</language>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>${start.class}</mainClass>
                    <layout>WAR</layout>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

The @entityscan was pointing to the wrong package in the ServiceConfiguration file. Fixed that and it works fine now. Thanks